# Firebase database ordering by keys number

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I have the below data structure in Firebase database and I would like to order keys of the 2017 branch as shown below in the screenshot. However when I get the keys the first items returned are 10, 11, 12 before 01, 02, 03, 04, 05, 06, 07, 08 ,09. The order should be as the screen shot.

My database call is

```
databaseRoot.ref('contractors/' + userObject.uid + '/timesheets').once('value', function(snapshot) { });
```

[image]

I also tried orderByKey() but I get the same results

Comment: I have changed my data structure to remove prefixed 0 and now all is the right order. Not the best approach but working fine. But there should be a way to order the above.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You were right to remove the prefixed 0. It's because Firebase Database keys are **strings ordered lexicographically**, and therefore it was returning them in an 'unnatural' looking order.